# Java RegExp get string between tags

Tags: java, regex

I need a regexp to get all string inside a tags like it:
<- -> inside this tags include any character, numbers, spaces, carriage return etc.
i have this regexp:

```
Pattern.compile("<-(.+?)->")
```

but it not detect a special sequence as: \r \n etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`but it not detect a special sequence as: \r \n etc`**

It won't match newline unless you use `Pattern.DOTALL` flag as in:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<-(.+?)->", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

OR else you can use `(?s)` flag:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)<-(.+?)->");
```

**`Pattern.DOTALL` makes dot match new line character so `.+?` will also match `\r`,`\n` etc.**

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
<-([\\S\\s]+?)->
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.` character does not match line breaks. This is why you are having the issue.